# How Callback parameter works using WebHCat/Hive?

Tags: spring, hadoop, hive, hql, hcatalog

I just followed the documentation in 
[WebHCat Reference Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+Hive)

my goal is to call my spring controller once hive job status SUCCEEDED.

```
**here are my inputs :** 

**url** : http://localhost:50111/templeton/v1/hive?user.name=hduser

**Parameter:**
callback : http://domain:port/project-name/mycall/$jobId
```

the $jobId is just a paramter it will be replaced to the actual jobId once processing is completed.

```
** here is my controller : ** 

@RequestMapping(value = "/mycall/{jobId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void callBack( @PathVariable String jobId) throws IOException {
LOGGER.debug("JobId : {}", jobId );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this sucsefully in node.js with express.  I'll try to explain though.

First I use the request module to submit the job

```
var cmd = "http://"+targ+":"+port+"/templeton/v1/hive";
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: cmd,
    form: {
        'user.name': user, // just a variable for user.name=
        'execute': query, // actual query string
        'statusdir': dir,  // directory results will go on hdfs
        'callback': "http://"+ip+":3000/callback/$jobId", // callback address
    }
}, function(err, response, body){
```

And now the route that receives the callback.

```
router.get('/:jobid', function(req, res) {
  var jobid = req.param('jobid');
  console.log(jobid, 'get: /callback/:jobid');
  i.alert(jobid);
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

the /callback is in the app.js that calls the route if your not familiar with node.